# Why isDragging prop is false in react-dnd simple sortable example with two columns?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

When dragging a card from one column to another then isDragging prop is always false. Why? What is wrong in the example?

Example: https://react-wdpn5f.stackblitz.io

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wdpn5f

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is set to true for the card you are dragging..
Just put

```
console.log("isDragging" + isDragging);
```

before

```
const opacity = isDragging ? 0 : 1
```

Then you can see isDragging is set to true in console.. For other cards, it is still false..

Comment: You forgot an important thing: "When dragging a card from one column to another". When dragging a card in the same column it is `true` and `opacity` is `0`, but when you drag a card to another column `isDragging` is `false` and card is visible because `opacity` is `1`.